# I keep getting "no such module 'Parse'" errors

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I've tried using Parse a couple of times.

Both times it works great at first but stops working if I stop using it for awhile, like if I close Safari or turn off my computer for the night.

When I try to run my app after that I get "no such module 'Parse'" errors.

Was I supposed to save it in a certain way or finalize the install?

Answer (score 0):

Click on your project, go to build settings and find the section called "Search Paths." Within that section find "Framework Search Paths" and set it to:

$(SRCROOT) and make it recursive.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Actuary.  I followed your suggestions and got as far as "Framework Search Paths".  Within it I found "Debug" and "Release" but can't seem to find a way to set it to $(SRCROOT) or make it recursive.  Thank you for helping me out :)

Comment: Click the space directly above Debug and put it there. You'll see :)

Comment: When I tried your suggestion the build failed and I got four more errors @theActuary. And honestly I don't understand any of them lol.  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFAnalytics", referenced from:
      __TMaCSo11PFAnalytics in AppDelegate.o